# Merge 2 duplicate xml nodes to one

Tags: c#, xml

I'm building a database with meets, clubs, results and a lot more for swimmers in the Netherlands. Due to some changes in the data i am receiving i'm running into a problem with duplicate values in the XML files i am reading.

Here is part of an XML file that causes problems :

```
<LENEX version="3.0">
  <MEETS>
    <MEET name="Speedowedstrijd 2012 - 2013 deel 1">
      <CLUB name="AZVD" type="CLUB" nation="NED" region="08" code="08-004">
        <OFFICIALS>
          <OFFICIAL nation="NED" gender="M" officialid="2329" lastname="xx">
            <CONTACT email="xx" phone="xx" country="NL" />
          </OFFICIAL>
        </OFFICIALS>
      </CLUB>
      <CLUB name="A.Z.V.D." type="CLUB" nation="NED" region="8" code="08-004">
        <ATHLETES>
          <ATHLETE nation="NED" gender="M" athleteid="2358" license="xx" lastname="xx">
            <RESULTS>
              <RESULT eventid="1167" resultid="2359" swimtime="00:03:09.69">
                <SPLITS>
                  <SPLIT distance="50" swimtime="00:00:40.71"/>
                  <SPLIT distance="100" swimtime="00:01:30.71"/>
                </SPLITS>
              </RESULT>
            </RESULTS>
          </ATHLETE>
        </ATHLETES>
      </CLUB>
    </MEET>
  </MEETS>
</LENEX>
```

Now the reading of the xml file is not a problem, using XDocument i get all the nodes, childs etc.
However, when i write the values to my database i get an keyconstraint error on the table Club_Meet. This table holds the link between the clubs table and the meet table and each conbination must be unique. As both clubs in the example above are pointing to the same club in my database (unique code = 08-004, i am trying to write the same values to the database twice, causing the error.

So waht i want to do is when i go through the xml file and find a club : check if this club was already found in this XML before and if so hang the childnodes under that first club-node.
The result of this action should be (internally) :

```
<LENEX version="3.0">
  <MEETS>
    <MEET name="Speedowedstrijd 2012 - 2013 deel 1">
      <CLUB name="AZVD" type="CLUB" nation="NED" region="08" code="08-004">
        <OFFICIALS>
          <OFFICIAL nation="NED" gender="M" officialid="2329" lastname="xx">
            <CONTACT email="xx" phone="xx" country="NL" />
          </OFFICIAL>
        </OFFICIALS>
        <ATHLETES>
          <ATHLETE nation="NED" gender="M" athleteid="2358" license="xx" lastname="xx">
            <RESULTS>
              <RESULT eventid="1167" resultid="2359" swimtime="00:03:09.69">
                <SPLITS>
                  <SPLIT distance="50" swimtime="00:00:40.71"/>
                  <SPLIT distance="100" swimtime="00:01:30.71"/>
                </SPLITS>
              </RESULT>
            </RESULTS>
          </ATHLETE>
        </ATHLETES>
      </CLUB>
    </MEET>
  </MEETS>
</LENEX>
```

Note that the second club-node `<CLUB name="A.Z.V.D." type="CLUB" nation="NED" region="8" code="08-004">` is removed completely, i dont need anything from that one.
How do i move the child nodes from one club to another and delete the empty club ?
Anyone that can point me in the right direction ?

(Hope this all makes some sense....)

Comment: first suggestion: i think this is also a question about database design/data structure. also, you could share some code with us that show us your current implementation of your data access layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so if you want to work strictly with the manipulation of your XML document, you can use the following extension method which I created.

```
public static class XmlExtensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<XElement> CombineLikeElements(this IEnumerable<XElement> source, Func<XElement, object> groupSelector)
   {
      // used to record the newly combined elements
      List<XElement> priElements = new List<XElement>();

      // group the current xml nodes by the supplied groupSelector, and only
      // select the groups that have more than 1 elements.
      var groups = source.GroupBy(groupSelector).Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1);

      foreach(var grp in groups)
      {
         // get the first (primary) child element and use it as 
         // element that all the other sibling elements get combined with.
         var priElement = grp.First();

         // get all the sibling elements which will be combined
         // with the primary element.  Skipping the primary element.
         var sibElements = grp.Skip(1);

         // add all the sibling element's child nodes to the primary
         // element.
         priElement.Add(sibElements.Select(node => node.Elements()));

         // remove all of the sibling elements
         sibElements.Remove();

         // add the primary element to the return list
         priElements.Add(priElement);
      }

      // return the primary elements incase we want to do some further
      // combining of their descendents
      return priElements;
   }
}
```

You would use the extension method as follows:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xmlDoc
   // Combine all of the duplicate CLUB nodes under each MEET node
   .Descendants("MEET").Descendants("CLUB").CombineLikeElements(node => node.Attribute("code").Value);
```

And it would return the results that you requested.

I have the extension method returning a list of the XElements which everything was combined into in case you want to combine their child nodes.  For example if after combining your identical CLUB elements, one or more of the CLUBs ends up having two or more ATHLETES or OFFICIALS nodes you can could combine those easily as well by doing the following:

```
xmlDoc
   // Combine all of the duplicate CLUB nodes under each MEET node
   .Descendants("MEET").Descendants("CLUB").CombineLikeElements(node => node.Attribute("code").Value)
   // Combine all of the duplicate ALTHLETES or OFFICIALS nodes under the newly combined CLUB nodes
   .Elements().CombineLikeElements(node => node.Name);
```

Comment: There may some bugs still but I have tested this with LINQPad and everything seems to work nicely.